# AngularJS - Override CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, ag-grid

I've inherited an AngularJS project which uses the 3rd party grid, Ag-grid.  There is an ag-grid-style.css file that has the following:

```
.ag-pinned-left-header.hasCategoryCol .ag-header-cell, .ag-pinned-left-cols-viewport.hasCategoryCol .ag-row .ag-cell {
    width: calc(100% / 7) !important;
}
```

This works great for the grid already in use, the grid is nicely divided into 7 columns.
My problem is I have created new code, also using ag-grid, but I need the new grid divided into 6 columns, not 7.  I end up with one extra empty column.  Using Chrome for debugging and going into the developer tools, I can see the above CSS and if I change the 7 to a 6, my grid displays perfectly.  My question is what is the easiest way to accomplish what I want?  I've been trying to adjust the styling in code but haven't succeeded yet.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply add the modified CSS to a CSS file that renders *after* all other third-party library CSS files. When you have an `!important` that happens *after* another `!important`, the second one overrides the first. So by adding the CSS to your website it should be fine.

```
.ag-pinned-left-header.hasCategoryCol .ag-header-cell, .ag-pinned-left-cols-
viewport.hasCategoryCol .ag-row .ag-cell {
    width: calc(100% / 6) !important;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps instead of in "base" or "main", it would be better to suggest that it instead be simply in a CSS file loaded *after* the 3rd party library. The OP's project may load the 3rd party assets after their regular CSS, after all.

Comment: I created a new css file that is linked from the new html page.  It worked for the column headers but not the body of the grid.

Comment: Is it possible the body of the grid uses a different CSS rule? Perhaps the one you pasted into your question was only for the header.

Comment: I considered that but when I changed the 7 to a 6 in the inspector the grid body changed also

Comment: My bad, when I pasted the css into its own file, a space was inadvertently inserted to the styling for the body.  Works great and so easy!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@Adosi's answer is the preferred solution -- CSS after all refers to *cascading* style sheets. If, however, you cannot modify the load order of your styles, the following is an alternative solution.

You can override a rule defined in an external stylesheet that has a `!important` attribute by adding your own definition inline to the element itself. I have demonstrated here using the `background-color` property as it is more obvious.

```css
#foo {
  background-color: pink !important;
}
```

```html
<p id="foo" style="background-color: cyan !important;">This paragraph has id foo.</p>
```

The inline style will always take precedence -- eg be loaded last -- so the color defined there is the one that is displayed.

Note that this is not considered a good practice, but I indicate it as an alternative if you are unable to load a CSS rule after your third party asset. (You may wish to log a bug with the 3rd party library because the `!important` annotation should be used sparingly and in this case probably not at all.)